# AWS Glue Crawler creating one table for each snappy parquet file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, parquet, amazon-athena, snappy

I see similar issues searching and I have adjusted my AWS Glue Crawler config to:

1. Exclude a directory called "Supporting Documents" (which has pdf's and csv's about the data) via the exclude `*/Supporting Documents/*`
2. Had Glue "Create a single schema for each S3 path"

The format of the bucket is as follows:

```
data_0_0_0.snappy.parquet
data_0_0_1.snappy.parquet
data_0_0_2.snappy.parquet
...so on for ~250 files...
Supporting Documents/ (which contains a pdf, xsls and csv)
```

It doesn't appear Glue is respecting the exclude, because I get `HIVE_BAD_DATA: Not valid Parquet file MYFILEBLAH` in Athena when I attempt to query the table.

Additionally, previously it was creating a database table in athena for EVERY parquet/snappy file, even though I told it "create a single schema...".

I also tried to specifically exclude those files, but it doesn't seem like that's working.

I did additional excludes:

```
**/*.csv
**/*.pdf
**/*.xlsx
```

I pulled down a couple files and they have matching column headers.

Any help is apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the directory and it worked. I couldn't get the excludes to work.